Is there a way to drop null or empty columns in azure workbook using KQL?
I have a log analytics workspace function which runs a query to created table in azure workbook to display results.
I am switching column names based on if the Locale is EN or FR. I am able to create columns based on the Locale but I want to drop the column which does not meet the Locale and is set as empty
Here is a small set of my KQL
|project 
ItemName = iff("fr-CA" == "en-CA",  strcat(ItemName_s, iff(Required_s=="False"," (R)", " (M)")), ""),
["Nom de l article"] = iff("fr-CA" == "fr-CA", strcat(ItemName_s, iff(Required_s=="False"," (R)", " (M)")), "")

I have two columns, ItemName and ["Nom de l article"]. How can I dynamically check all of these columns and drop the ones which are empty?
I have tried using project-away, project-keep and extend commands but can't put a logical way of dropping the empty columns.

You can use pack_all() function to pack all the values into a single column and then unpack that column using bag_unpack() function. This will remove the empty columns. Below is the sample code:
datatable(strCol:string, realCol:real, longCol:long, dynamicCol:dynamic)
[
    "strVal", real(null),3, dynamic({"foo":"bar"})
]
| project packed = pack_all()
| evaluate bag_unpack(packed)

Here, realCol field has null value. While packing and unpacking this column is removed.
demo
